# Call action of my controller from WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Need : Call action of my controller from WebForms and set result in specific div.

My Web Application is writted in Webforms and Mvc
I need to replace in my Webforms my user control written in Webforms, with another view written in MVC.

So how call view of mvc in my webform, I must call`Webforms1.Aspx`, and the content must contains my view mvc and anothers views.
But without use Reponse.Redirect, because the full stream is printed, but I must print view mvc in small div.

I try to write helper which permit me print mvc view

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="MvcApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>
<% RoutingWebFormSimulator.RenderViewMvc("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"); %>
```

In my helper, I search to invoke action by reflection, but without result.

Comment: Whilst webforms & MVC can exist together in the same site, they can't really interact with each other as they both have their own processing pipeline. About the best you can hope for is as @MikeSmithDev has suggested below

Answer (score 0):

I would think the easiest way would be to pull it in via AJAX, where `somePath` is the URL as you would hit it (not direct to a .cshtml file like in your question). I've used a method similar to this to pull in partials into an `aspx` page. Can include a javascript only version if you aren't using jQuery:

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "somePath",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#example").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```